# Fullcalendar 4 not working today in a custom buttom

Tags: fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I have a custom button that i want to go today day.

```
 customButtons: {
      myCustomButton: {
        text: 'Día Actual',
        click: function(info) {
          calendar.fullCalendar('today');
        }
      }
    }
```

But my error is a fullCalendar('today') dont exist on v4. I can do this the other way

Answer (score 1):

You're correct that `calendar.fullCalendar('today');` no longer works in version 4. However this is simply due to a change of syntax. It has been directly replaced by the [today](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-today) method. Therefore this code:

```
click: function(info) {
  calendar.today();
}
```

will solve your problem.

This change of syntax is explained in the [v3 to v4 upgrade guide](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/upgrading-from-v3#core-changes) and there is a more detailed article in the v4 documentation about [calling methods](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/methods) as well.

---

However I'd also like to point out that if all your button does is change to today's date, you don't even need a custom button at all! As documented in the [header options](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/header) you can simply put `today` as one of the buttons in the header and fullCalendar will auto-generate a button which moves to today's date.

e.g.

```
{
  left:   'title',
  center: '',
  right:  'today prev,next'
}
```

This is visible in most of the demos on the fullCalendar site, including the ones on the home page: https://fullcalendar.io/#demos

Answer (score -1):

I did the following is not the best but it works for me

```
customButtons: {
      myCustomButton: {
        text: 'Día Actual',
        click: function(info) {
          location.href="http://localhost:8888/Proyecto/calendario-plantillas";
        }
      }
    },
```